# Saber cuantas veces un caracter se repite consecutivamente en python

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa que verifica cuantas veces un carácter se repite consecutivamente en la cadena y eliminar las repeticiones.
Por ejemplo, si se ingresa como entrada:

```
A-A-A-C-X-S-S
```

La salida será

```
ACXS
3112
```

Estoy intentando con este código:

```
caracteres_primer = input('')

def eliminar_guiones(car):
    global cadena_separada
    cadena_separada = ''
    for i in car:
        if i == '-':
            continue
        else:
            cadena_separada += i

def resultado(cad):
    cadena_numeros = ''
    eliminar_guiones(cad)
    cadena_final = ''
    for i in cadena_separada:
        cont = 1
        for j in range(len(cadena_separada)):
            if i == cadena_separada[j+1]:
                cont += 1
            else:
                cadena_final = cadena_final + i
        cont = str(cont)
        cadena_numeros += cont
    print(cadena_final + '\n' + cadena_numeros)

resultado(caracteres_primer)
```

¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar a verificar qué esta mal?

Comment: Es mejor dejar tu avance en la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solución *nativa* (sin librerias)

```
texto = "A-A-A-C-X-S-S" + "--"
prev = texto[0]
contador = 1
for letra in texto[2::2]:
    if letra == prev:
        contador += 1
    else:
        print(prev, contador)
        contador = 1
    prev = letra
```

produce

```
A 3
C 1
X 1
S 2
```

**Explicación**

Usando rebanado de listas podemos recorrer el texto de dos en dos, saltando los caracteres "-". Eso simplifica el `for`.

Agregue un "--" al texto para poder procesar con el mismo código las repeticiones que se producen al final del texto.

El ciclo consiste en chequear que la `letra` actual sea igual a la anterior (en `prev`). Si es así, se incrementa el contador.

Si no son iguales, se imprime la letra previa y su cuenta. Luego se reinicia el contador.

#### Una solución usando `itertools`

```
import itertools

texto = "A-A-A-C-X-S-S"
for k, g in itertools.groupby(texto.replace("-", ""), key=lambda x: x):
    print(k, len(list(g)))
```

produce:

```
A 3
C 1
X 1
S 2
```

**Explicación**

La función `groupby` agrupa los valores de un iterable según el valor dado por el parámetro `key=`. En este caso, el iterable es un texto, y la llave es cada letra del texto.

```
itertools.groupby(texto.replace("-", ""), key=lambda x: x)
```

La función retorna pares `key, grupo`, donde `key` es la letra (en este caso) y `grupo` devuelve los elementos agrupados. Puede convertir `grupo` en lista para contar sus elementos

```
print(k, len(list(g)))
```

Comment: La idea del programa es que haga eso, pero no puedo hacerlo con librerias, la verdad, no encuentro manera de hacer bien el conteo de modo vanilla :/

Comment: @David. Edite mi respuesta agregando una solución sin librerías.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

desconozco el enfoque del ejercicio, pero se puedo apreciar que la funcion eliminar guiones se puede reemplazar con un replace, que es una funcion nativa de python, usas `cad.replace("-","")` y los guiones se iran.
Con respecto al contador tu for se pasa del rango, podrias leerla hasta `len(cad)-1` y el problema se iria, repito desconozco el trasfondo del codigo, pero dejare uno mas optimizado para que lo revises.

```
caracteres_primer = input('')

caracteres_primer = caracteres_primer.replace("-","")

def resultado(cad):
    cadena_final = "".join(set(cad))
    reps = ""
    for i in cadena_final:
        reps += str(cad.count(i))
    print(cadena_final,"\n", reps)


resultado(caracteres_primer)
```

Comment: El tema es que el count() no se puede utilizar porque estamos contando las letras repetidas consecutivas, es decir, si se entra AAAXCASSAA la salida debe ser 311122 , osea, si después se repite la misma letra sin tener una igual ya contada precediendola debe dejar el número.

Comment: aaah mala mia amigo, no habia entendido bien jsjs