# debo hacer un programa que verifique cuantas veces se repite un carácter consecutivamente en la cadena y eliminar las repeticiones

Tags: python

Este es el código de prueba que hice, pero esto debe servir con cualquier combinación de letras que se le ingrese, ósea con un input, pero no se como hacer para que sea eso lo que el diccionario tenga en cuenta.

```
letras = ["a", "a", "c", "a"]

diccionario = {}
contador = 0

for letra in letras:
   if letra == "a":
       contador += 1
       diccionario[letra] = contador
   else:
       contador -= 1


for llave, valor in diccionario.items():
  print(f"{llave}\n{valor}")
```

Y esta es una imagen de ejemplo de la entrada y la salida que debe tener el programa, agradecería su ayuda y correciones.

[image: Ejemplo de entrada y salida del programa]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Los ejercicios deben tener un intento de resolucion. Si obtenes una cadena, tenes que verificar si el caracter que estas leyendo es igual al anterior (que para el primero, es ninguno) y luego llevar la cuenta de esas repeticiones hasta cambiar de caracter... intentalo!

Comment: Esta pregunta es prácticamente igual que [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/465937/obtener-frecuencias-recorridas-de-acuerdo-al-caracter-lista), que a su vez es copia de [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/464876/saber-cuantas-veces-un-caracter-se-repite-consecutivamente-en-python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno yo lo implemente de la siguiente manera:

```
elem = list(map(str, input().split()))
```

Declaro una variable llamada elem donde almacenare los caracteres ingresado por teclado, utilizo el objecto iterador map.
Despues declaro dos listas donde en una almacenare las letras y en otro la cantidad de veces que se repite.
Despues declaro un auxiliar llamado aux donde alamcenare en primera instancia el primer elemento ingresado `aux = elem[0]`.
Por ultimo declaro e inicializo una variable llamada c conde se almacenara la cantidad de veces que se repite un caracter es como un contador.

```
lista_elemento = []
lista_cantidad = []
aux = elem[0]
c=0
```

Bueno aca viene lo mas importante espero ser claro y ojo se que puede mejorar el algoritmo y la logica...

```
for i in range(len(elem)):
  if(elem[i]==aux):
    c=c+1
  else:
    lista_elemento.append(aux)
    lista_cantidad.append(c)
    c=1
    aux=elem[i]
lista_elemento.append(elem[i])
lista_cantidad.append(c)
```

Primero en el for voy a recorrer cada uno de los elementos que se almacenaron en elem.

Despues en `if(elem[i]==aux):` voy a verificar si el caracter de mi primera posicion es igual a auxiliar si es asi que contador incremente `c=c+1`.
Lo logica aca es .. mientras se cumpla la condicion contador va a incrementar.

Despues Si no se cumple la condicion almacenamos el caracter y la cantidad acumulada en el if anterior en su lista respectiva, para despues limpiarlo y darle un valor de  `c=1` porque ya que estamos en el nuevo caracter por eso le doy a c=1, despues `aux=elem[i]` a la varaible auxiliar cambia de caracter y lo asigno al nuevo caracter que voy a trabajar.

Por utlimo tenemos lo siguiente:

```
lista_elemento.append(elem[i])
lista_cantidad.append(c)
```

Bueno lo que hice fue ya que al ultimo caracter y su contador, el algoritmo de arriba no lo guardaba, lo tuve que hacer al final ya se va a hacer el ultimo recorrido que te bota el bucle y lo almacene como lo vez pero agregando el `elem[i]` y despues su cantidad `c`. eso es todo ..

Después ya solo mostramos los resultados en el bucle for..

```
for i in range(len(lista_elemento)):
  print(lista_elemento[i],end=" -> ")
  print(lista_cantidad[i])
```

ejemplo:

```
D D D D T T T D A A T T T A A A U Y U U U
D -> 4
T -> 3
D -> 1
A -> 2
T -> 3
A -> 3
U -> 1
Y -> 1
U -> 3
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvió mucho y aprendí cosas nuevas, pues apenas llevo como 1 mes en este mundo.

Comment: como haría para que la salida en vez de salir verticalmente, lo haga de forma horizontal, no como la salida que tu hiciste, si no como se muestra en la imagen de ejmplo? es que lo estoy intentando pero no me sale.

Answer (score 0):

Esto te podria servir:

```
 
letras = ["a", "a", "c", "a"]
diccionario = {}

for letra in letras:
    if(letra in diccionario):
        diccionario[letra] +=1
    else:
        diccionario[letra] = 1
```

no es necesario el contador y solo debes buscar si la letra ya esta en el diccionario y si no se encuentra entonces la agregas al diccionario en 1.

y para imprimirlas puedes hacer esto:

```
print(list(diccionario))
print(list(diccionario.values()))
```

o:

```
for llave,valor in diccionario.items():
    print(llave, end="\t")

print("")

for llave,valor in diccionario.items():
    print(valor,end="\t")
```

Depende de como te lo pidan e incluso puede haber alguna mejor forma de imprimirlo..
te dejo un enlace que te puede servir:
https://j2logo.com/python/tutorial/tipo-dict-python/#dict-in

Comment: esto cuenta las letras de forma general, pero lo que se pide es que cuente solo las consecutivas

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa  a lo que deseas es hacerlo utilizando expresiones regulares de la siguiente forma:

Con la siguiente expresión regular: `(\w)\1*` indicamos que capture una letra `\w`. `(\w)`  agrupa cada letra. `\1` seguido  de la letra capturada anteriormente. En pocas palabras la expresión `(\w)\1*` va a capturar todas las letras iguales.

Eso nos basta  para programarlo en  Python:

```
# importamos la libreria de expresiones regulares
import re
# nuestra expresion  regular
regex = r"(\w)\1*"

#  texto de  prueba  
test_str = "TTTTTTTDDDDDDYYYYYYYUUUUDDIII"

#test_str =  "YYYTAAYYYYAAADDDDBBBBUUUAAAAG"
#test_str  = "BBBBGGGGUAAAAUUUUUUUGGGGDDDYAAAA"


letras=""
numeros=""

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    numeros+=str(match.end() - match.start())
    letras+=match.group(1)
    
print(letras)
print(numeros)
```

Con lo anterior obtenemos los resultados de la imagen que adjuntaste a tu pregunta.  Ahora si quieres contar cuantas letras se repiten en total. Le añades el diccionario al for para que acumule por letra.

Si  quieres manejar arreglos:

```
import re
regex = r"(\w)\1*"

test_arr = ['D','D','D','D','T','T','T','D','A','A','T','T','T','A','A','A','U','Y','U','U','U']


#test_arr = ['T','T','T','T','T','T','T','D','D','D','D','D','D','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','U','U','U','U','D','D','I','I','I']
test_str = "".join(test_arr)

letras=[]
numeros=[]
diccionario={}
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    numeros.append(match.end() - match.start())
    letras.append(match.group(1))
    cant = diccionario.get(match.group(1)) or  0
    diccionario[match.group(1)] = cant + (  match.end() - match.start()    )

print("".join(letras))

print("".join((str(x) for x  in  numeros)))
print(diccionario)
```