# Ajustar Contador para que imprima letras sin orden especifico python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, count

Disculpen la molestia,

Estoy tratando de de realizar el siguiente código que imprima las siguientes entradas de la siguiente manera "salidas", hay que aclarar que se debe imprimir la salida tal cual con espacios y con un salto de linea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
sin embargo  al intentar realizar el código:

```
entradas_user = input("ingrese la lista de viajes realizados separados por un espacio: ").split(" ")
lista = entradas_user
entradas_user.append(" ")
contador = 1
cadena_contador = ""


for indice in range((len(lista)-1)):
    
    if lista[indice] == lista[indice+1]:     
       contador += 1 
    cadena_contador = cadena_contador + str(contador)     
contador = 1     

print(cadena_contador)
```

me imprime, lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo que estoy haciendo mal. ¿Alguien me podría, brindar una mano? de antemano mil gracias.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**
Este es el código resuelto de  la manera que lo necesitaba, probablemente existan muchas cosas por mejorar pero al menos lo logré ejecutar tal cuál como se mostraba en la imagen, Muchas gracias por la ayuda que todos me brindaron en este post.

```
entradas_user = input("ingrese la lista de viajes realizados separados por un espacio: ")
lista = entradas_user.split(" ")
contador = 1
cadena_contador = ""
cadena_palabras = ""


for indice in range((len(lista)-1)):
    
    if lista[indice] == lista[indice+1]:     
        contador += 1 
    else:
        cadena_contador = cadena_contador + str(contador) + " "
        cadena_palabras = cadena_palabras + lista[indice]   + " "  
        contador = 1     

cadena_contador = cadena_contador + str(contador)
cadena_palabras = cadena_palabras + lista[indice + 1]

print(cadena_palabras)
print(cadena_contador)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Saber cuantas veces un caracter se repite consecutivamente en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/464876/saber-cuantas-veces-un-caracter-se-repite-consecutivamente-en-python)

Comment: No. Lo que necesito es imprimir todos los valores cada vez que aparezcan si que se ordenen en una sola letra, tal y como lo muestro en la imagen de arriba. Pero muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en el bucle for, particularmente con las indentaciones y la sentencia 'if'. Prueba utilizando el siguiente código:

```
for indice in range((len(lista)-1)):

    if lista[indice] == lista[indice+1]:     
        contador += 1
    else:
        cadena_contador = cadena_contador + str(contador)     
        contador = 1
```

Te detallaría un poco mas como se ejecuta pero la burocracia no me lo permitió (me empezó a tirar un error de que el texto tenía que tener formato de código y bla bla en fin jaja). Básicamente el contador suma hasta que el siguiente caracter es distinto, y una vez ahí, el mismo se agrega a "cadena_contador", el contador vuelve a cero e inicia un nuevo ciclo.

Espero sea de ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: Con este código la cantidad del último grupo de caracteres no te lo imprimiría.

Comment: Lo imprime... El contador ya parte en uno, por lo que al tomar la posición del último elemento, chequea la sentencia 'if', y al no existir el elemento siguiente se ejecuta el 'else', incorporando el número en el que haya quedado el contador

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, no había visto que el OP había incluido un espacio al final de la lista.

Comment: Corregí el código con el ese que me sugeriste y ya me cuenta las letras y puedo ver los números con el print, pero como haria para agregar al print los numeros debajo de las letras para que me lo muestre tal y como está en la imagen?

Comment: Actualización ya lo pude, resolver muchas gracias a todos los que respondieron este post, ustedes son lo máximo. <3

Comment: ¡Buenisimo que hayas podido resolver!. Por si no lo conoces te recomiendo que leas sobre f-strings. Te dá bastante versatilidad a la hora  de dar formato a los datos. Saludos!